# hashtable Synchronization

Tags: java, collections

is whole Hashtable object is syncronized?
I Know,Get and Put methods are synchronized.
Is it mean, each entries in the Hashtable are synchronized?

If i have a hash object hsObj, and have 3 key-value pairs "a->sun" "b->tue" and "c->wed"
then while getting one entry values we can put other entry values but we cant put or get at the same entry location.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Whole `Hashtable` object is syncronized. If you want more concurrent `Map` you might look into `ConcurrentHashMap`. Here is a good resource : http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_8_hashmap.shtml.

Comment: What information i need is-> is it possible to insert an entry while retriving another entry? means i will be accessing c->wed entry, same time i will be editing a->sun. 

I want to know, whether each entry is synchronized ( while making changes to a->sun we cant access it)or whole hashtable is synchronized (while making changes to a->sun we can access c->wed)